# How to let the Android/iOS code of one Flutter plugin depend on that of another Flutter plugin?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, dependencies

Concrete example: Say I have an app `my_app`, Flutter plugin `plugin_utility` and Flutter plugin `plugin_b`.

The `plugin_utility` has some helper Android/iOS code. (For a concrete example, it has a `sendLogFromNativeToDart(String)` function that sends a log string from Android/iOS to Dart(Flutter) and manipulate them there.)

Thus, I want the Android/iOS code of `plugin_b` to depend on the respective Android/iOS code of `plugin_utility`.

However, how can I do it? Thanks for any suggestions!

Notice that, I am not talking about "let one flutter package to depend on another", which simply needs `pubspec

Comment: did you find any solution on this?